# Which PostgreSQL replication solution(s) would work for me?

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a python/django website with a PostgreSQL database.

I need to set up replication so that:

- *standby* server will be on a different Linux box
- if the *main* server fails, the *standby* server can take over with minimal data loss (up to 1 hour)
- the *standby* server can be used in "read-only" mode - a duplicate code would run a duplicate website, where the users could see the information, but wouldn't be able to create/update/delete records

The last requirement means that the *standby* server would accept

- read-only queries for most tables, except
- insert/update/delete for "django_session" table

Another consideration is also ease of implementation, and ease of turning *standby* into *main* in case of failure.

I'm reading [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/different-replication-solutions.html), and there are several options:

1. Shared Disk Failover -- *This is probably not what I need*
2. File System (Block Device) Replication
3. Write-Ahead Log Shipping
4. Logical Replication
5. Trigger-Based Primary-Standby Replication
6. SQL-Based Replication Middleware
7. Asynchronous Multimaster Replication
8. Synchronous Multimaster Replication

I've never done any replication, so I'm lost, as I try to decipher the descriptions...

Which one(s) would satisfy my requirements?

Comment: Items 4 through 8 would satisfy your requirement, but that's not your actual question, is it?

Comment: You need asynchronous streaming replication.

Comment: @mustaccio I wanted to decide which chapters to skip when reading the manual, so your comment is helpful. But the ultimate question is, how to implement the thing.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe could you add an answer and elaborate?

Comment: You already got an answer that is as good as possible. I know that you want to get a detailed tutorial for setting up your system, but that is not what Stackexchange is for: it is for concrete answers to focused questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you planning to replicate all tables and database itself is quite big in size `Streaming replication` will do all the requirements you mentioned above. For streaming replication you need to have same Postgres and OS version on all servers participating. By default `replica` server for `streaming replication` is **read-only**  and the one table you mentioned can easily control using **user rights**.

Streaming replication can setup using just one command on built-in utility called `pg_basebackup`.

However if you need an **automated failover** mechanism you would need additional tools like `repmgr` or `patroni` etc . The data loss tolerance vs write performance can be adjusted using setting `synchronous_commit` parameter. Failover itself is only one promote command using `pg_ctl` and it's so fast, only brining back the old `primary` as new `replica` is where you need some plans in advance.

If you planning to replicate only a subset of tables then `logical replication` is the solution. But once the failover done old `publisher` data needs to initialise from scratch which require setup replication again from new `publisher` .

Comment: All the servers are Ubuntu (so same OS), and I'm responsible for installing and maintaining Postgres, and I keep same version on all servers.

Comment: Could you add links to those additional tools? Are they third party?

Comment: https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-implement-repmgr-postgresql-automatic-failover

Comment: Yes those are third party but most of them free of cost and open source. https://severalnines.com/blog/best-free-community-tools-for-postgresql/